# from an id, how to get a path for different pages in django

Tags: python, django

I am creating a web page,it is for a restaurant. there is an image slide show. all the thing of slide show dynamic..load from the database. My problem is.. there is a button of the each slid to go to different pages. as an example one slide for wine section another is for menu another for special plates. another for another page so on...my html template is this [enter link description here][1]
[1]: https://colorlib.com/wp/template/eatery/ how can i give the path to the each different pages.

```html
  my urls.py

    urlpatterns = [
        path('', home, name='home' ), 
    ]
```

```html
my views.py

def home(request):
    image_gallery = Gallery.objects.all()
    context = {'galleries':image_gallery}
    return render(request, 'restaurant/index.html', context)
```

```html
my html template with for loop

<section class="home-slider owl-carousel">
    {% for gallery in galleries %}
    <div class="slider-item" style="background-image:url('{{gallery.image.url}}')">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row slider-text align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-8 text-center col-sm-12 element-animate">
                    <h1>{{gallery.image_title}}</h1>
                    <p class="mb-5">
                        {{gallery.image_description}}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="{% url'' id= gallery.id  %}" class="btn btn-white btn-outline-white">{{gallery.image_button}}</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</section>
```

```html
My models.py

class Gallery(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, )
    image_title = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=200)
    image_description = models.TextField()
    image_button = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=20)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have a url path where you can add a name this way

```
path('teacherprofile/', views.teacher_profile_view, name='teacher-profile'),
```

and than access the name of the url this way

```
<a href="{% url 'teacher-profile' %}"> Button </a>
```

This way it redirects the user to whichever path its refering to.